# powder gem, error on install

Tags: ruby, rack-pow

After installing `powder` gem, I run:

```
$ powder install
```

the output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  9039  100  9039    0     0   8600      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  8608

/Users/name/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/lib/command.js:78
            throw err;
                  ^
file exists
```

That `file exist` does not tell me much though.
Any ideas what could've gone wrong? Maybe I should report it on gem issues page?
I was installing it on mac.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an issue with pow](https://github.com/basecamp/pow/issues/320) about this problem. There are a few suggestions over there, but the one solution that seemed most likely to help was to remove `~/.pow` and reinstall. The rather unhelpful error message came from [this line](https://github.com/basecamp/pow/blob/master/src/util.coffee#L67):

```
      callback "file exists"
```

It would have been helpful if the developers of Pow included the filename instead of the generic message.

Judging from the code and the comments on the issue, the problem probably occurs when a directory that pow needs is a symlink to a directory. `lstat` does not count those as directories, but as symlinks. That seems like a bug in Pow.